# Remover elementos pares de uma lista simplesmente encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou fazendo uma função para remover TODOS os elementos pares de uma lista simplesmente encadeada, porém, quando executo o sistema, só eh removido um elemento par a cada vez que chamo a função. Ex: Elementos={2, 4, 5, 3}, se eu chamo a função, ela apaga o elemento 4, e depois que chamo novamente, apaga o 2.
Alguém sabe fazer essa função apagar todos os elementos pares de uma vez?

```
int remover_pares(struct no **c){
struct no *p, *q;
if(*c==NULL){
    printf("LISTA VAZIA");
    return 0;
}
else{
    p=*c;
    q=*c;
    for(p=*c;p!=NULL;p=p->prox){
        if(p->dado%2==0){
            if(p==*c){
                *c=(*c)->prox;
                free(p);
                return 1;
            }else{
                q->prox=p->prox;
                free(p);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Vc sai da função `return 1` sempre que encontra um elemento par, desta forma ela não percorre a sua lista, e precisara chama-la de novo como já acontece. Não sei se há a necessidade do `return 1`.

Comment: Entendi.... é mesmo, obrigada!